# Thumbnails with carrierwave_direct or s3_direct_upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thumbnails, carrierwave

Is it possible to generate thumbnails using carrierwave_direct or s3_direct_upload uploading an image direct to amazon s3? I'm with a problem and didn't found the best solution for me yet. I need image thumbnails, my amazon server has a timeout and I can't send large files to my application and sending directly I did not found any way to make thumbs. I'm thinking about limit the image size before upload, have I any other options?